# How to combine two cells experience into one

Tags: excel-formula

We have gathered data from participants for job. Now we have data in the form given below.

Experience-1(Cell1) (5 Years 4 Month) Experience-2(Cell2) (4 Year 9 Month)

Now want to combine both cells experience and want to calculate the total experience like 10 Years 1 Month

Comment: Dear, Experience is always is x year and y month.

Comment: will there be variations such as  `x years y month` vs `x year y months` or they will always be `x years y months` or `x year y month` one way or another? That's why I would like you to edit your post to share more sample data. Also do you just want a sum at the end of the cells or do you need to sum the experience by other criteria such as candidate ID for instance?

Comment: no , we just want to sum the experience of the candidate.

Comment: any help please,

Comment: I think a UDF (user defined function which is in `vba`) may be the most efficient way of solving your case. I haven't tested the UDF provided by user3819867 but if you are open to `vba` you may want to give it a go. If I have time I will share my solution using excel formulas which require a few helper cells/columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the wording for experiences will always be in the form of `x Year(s) y Month(s)`, and all experiences are listed in a column such as below:

[image: Example]

Presume you have given a **name** to the above list as **List_Exp**, you can use the following **array formula**, which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar, to find the **total months** first:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(List_Exp," ",REPT(" ",100)),{1,200},100)),IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(List_Exp)))>0,{12,1}))
```

> Here I used **TRIM+MID+SUBSTITUTE+REPT** functions to extract the year and month figure from the original string, which is `{5,4;4,9;1,2;1,1;10,9}` from the above example, then use **SUMPRODUCT** to work out the total months by finding corresponding multipliers `{12,1;12,1;12,1;12,1;12,1}` using **IF+ROW+INDEX** functions.

Then you can convert the **Total Months** to **Years** and **Months** as shown below:

[image: Solution]

If you do not want to use helper cells (Cell `D3:D6`) in the above example, you can give a name to the **Total Months** figure as **Ttl_Mth**, and combine the following formulas into one:

Figure for Years: `=INT(Ttl_Mth/12)`

Word for Years: `="Year"&IF(INT(Ttl_Mth/12)>1,"s","")`

Figure for Months: `=MOD(Ttl_Mth,12)`

Word for Months: `="Month"&IF(MOD(Ttl_Mth,12)>1,"s","")`

**Combined:**

```
=INT(Ttl_Mth/12)&" "&"Year"&IF(INT(Ttl_Mth/12)>1,"s","")&" "&MOD(Ttl_Mth,12)&" "&"Month"&IF(MOD(Ttl_Mth,12)>1,"s","")
```

Please see below a test result for a new list of experiences:

[image: Test Result]

> **[Hint]** I recommend to convert the list of experiences into a **Table** before giving a name to the list. The benefit is that each time you add or replace values in the list (which is actually a one-column table), the named range will be automatically updated so the calculations will also be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For vanilla Excel formulas it's a bit though. Supposing your string is in cell `A2` your values can be calculated using the following logic:
You can look for the first number with the following formula:

```
=MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&"0123456789"))
```

and you can look for the last string with the following formula:

```
=MAX(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};1)))*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})
```

Presuming that none of your applicants have worked more than 99 years, a **TRIM** is adequate:

```
=TRIM(MID($A2;MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A2&"0123456789"));2))*1
```

years and

```
=TRIM(MID($A2;MAX(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID($A2;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};1)))*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})-1;2))
```

months.
To get a single number that can be summed, you store years as integers and add months divided by 12 as non-integer part

```
=TRIM(MID($A2;MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};$A2&"0123456789"));2))*1+TRIM(MID($A2;MAX(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID($A2;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};1)))*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})-1;2))/12
```

These numbers can be summed up and will result in `10.83333`. In order to get your string at the end, you will need to use a formula on the sum (in my example cell `X1`), e.g.

```
=INT(X1)&" Years " & ROUND((X1-INT(X1))*12;0) & " Months"
```

Please note you will probably need to formulate something even more complex unless your users maintain data as `0 Years 6 Months` for periods lower than 1 year.

Answer (score 0):

With a user-defined function it is easier to dodge the major drawbacks of long vanilla formulas:

```
Function sumyearmonth(rng As Range) As String
Dim rng2 As Range, strArr() As String, runtotal As Double, outYear As Long, outMonth As Long

For Each rng2 In rng ' for each of the cells
    strArr = Split(rng2.Value2, " ") 'splits any sort of string by spaces
    For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr) ' for each element of the array
        Select Case True
            Case strArr(i) Like "*year*" Or strArr(i) Like "*Year*" 'if it says something like "year", "Year" or "Years"
                runtotal = runtotal + Val(strArr(i - 1)) 'then the running total gets incremented by the preceding item of the array, e.g. 12 (years)
            Case strArr(i) Like "*month*" Or strArr(i) Like "*Month*"  'if it says something like "month", "Month" or "Months"
                runtotal = runtotal + Val(strArr(i - 1)) / 12 'then the running total gets incremented by the preceding item of the array, e.g. 9 (months) /12
        End Select
    Next i
Next rng2
'now we just need to interpret the running total
outYear = Int(runtotal) 'years is the integer part of the running total
outMonth = Round((runtotal - outYear) * 12, 0) 'months is the noninteger part of the running total multiplied by 12 and rounded to the next integer
sumyearmonth = outYear & " Year" & IIf(outYear > 1, "s", "") 'if it's more than 1 year, then years
sumyearmonth = sumyearmonth & " " & outMonth & " Month" & IIf(outMonth > 1, "s", "") 'if it's more than 1 month, then months
End Function
```

This solution doesn't presume that the input comes as Year AND Month, it has a nice output format [Year(s)] and you don't need to have a running total shown alongside.